# Ocultar url en navegador

Tags: .htaccess, url, ftp

Mis directorios están hechos de la siguiente manera:

```
dominio
|_carpeta-ftp
   |_carpetaA
   |    |_Doc1
   |    |_Doc2
   |_carpetaB
```

Necesito ocultar la url de una interfaz web de ftp. El cliente accedería desde `www.dominio.es/carpeta-ftp`, esa carpeta tiene distintos subcarpetas, pero el cliente solo puede ver la dirección que le mandamos. Pongo un ejemplo
El cliente A tiene que acceder a `/www.dominio.es/carpeta-ftp/CarpetaA/Documento1`, pero no tiene que poder volver atrás, ya que fuera de esa ruta hay otros ficheros para otros clientes.

La idea es que el cliente acceda a la ruta `/www.dominio.es/carpeta-ftp/CarpetaA/Documento1` pero que la url muestre solo `www.dominio.es` o `www.dominio.es/Documento1`.

He intentado añadiendo líneas al .htaccess, pero no hace lo que quiero, o me tira error 404. Este es el código que tengo actualmente, sin las pruebas que hice anteriormente:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
IndexIgnore ..
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Y este uno de los que probé:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^carpeta-ftp/CarpetaA/doc1/?$ "/$1" [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^doc1/?$ "carpeta-ftp/CarpetaA/$1/" [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
IndexIgnore ..
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Y sigue igual que antes. No sé que estoy haciendo mal... Uso un servidor Linux. Utilizo Apache, html, css y php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que no entendí bien, ¿es FTP como accedes o HTTP?

lo que puedes hacer en caso de que sea FTP es eenjaular a los usuarios para que no puedan salir de su carpeta, esto lo logras con un chroot_list (si por ejemplo usas vsftp) si es por HTTP entonces o puedes crear subdominios, o puedes hacer uso del mod_alias de apache.

Comment: Se accede desde la web `dominio.es/carpeta` Y cuando entras en esa dirección, sale la interfaz del ftp.
Investigaré sobre lo que me dijiste, ¡muchas gracias!